# Bad gateway 502 on rubygems.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Just wondering if anybody had the same problem with rubygems.org

I appluad the decision to consolidated everything on rubygems.org, but when the default was rubyforge - I never had any problems. Now it seems I have a problem updating gems everytime I do a new installation. I mean I can work around it, but downloading gems through the browser and then installing them manually - but that is very annoying.

The message I keep getting  bad response Bad Gateway 502 (name of some gem goes here).

It never breaks on the same gem, and I have mostly problems installing Rails stack - such as mail, railties, actionmailer, etc.

Other gems like  nokogori or haml - install without any problem.

If I run bundle - it also breaks with the same message or a variation thereof.

I tried obvious things - like removing rubygems.org from sources - pointing to rubyforge or rubyonrails, but keep getting the same problem. I tried it on 3 different machines - my Debian dev box, my Windows machine and my macbook, all running different subversions of Ruby 1.8.7.

Does anyone have any solution or suggestion please??? Pretty please?

P.S.:
By the way "wget" on certain gems from rubyforge.org - doesn't work - I'm getting the same error - downloading through the browser seems to be the only option. Which leads me to believe it has nothing to do with my ruby setup, but is actually a problem on rubygems.org .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has disappeared - can't recreate it anymore - so I assume it was a problem with the rubygems server, since nothing changed on my end.

Answer (score 4):

> Which leads me to believe it has nothing to do with my ruby setup, but is actually a problem on rubygems.org

Not necessarily. `502` only means that *some* gateway, somewhere, *anywhere*, between you and rubygems.org didn't respond properly. This could be pretty much any server that sits in between you and rubygems.org: your company's proxy, your company's firewall, your own proxy, your own firewall, (one of) your provider's prox(y/ies), (one of) your provider's firewall(s), (one of) rubygems.org's hosting provider's firewall(s), rubygems.org's load balancer, your government's web content filter, or really *any* other server that sits – for whatever reason – between you and rubygems.org.

It literally just means that somewhere on the internet there is a `Bad Gateway`.

Comment: Jorg - I see where you are coming from, but as i said - when I download the same gems manually through browser - it works just fine, but wget, and gem install don't work CONSISTENTLY. I really doubt that my wget or gem request is CONSISTENTLY routed through a bad gateway and my browser request - has a VIP privileges :-)  Also - I control our firewall - and I nothing nothing is blocking anything there. I mean nothing else has that problem - cpan, apt-get or even port on my macbook.